# Code for auto renaming files when they are extracted in BATCH?

Tags: batch-file, rename

I want to extract multiple zip files with the same name in the same path all in on go.

This is the kind of thing I'm doing (note: I'm using 7-Zip to extract)(also, each "t100.zip" is inside of each other)

```
    PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip.exe
    echo %PATH%

    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x t100.zip 

    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x t100.zip

    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x t100.zip
```

Is there a way so that the files are automatically renamed? I have heard that there is a command that tells cmd to always select "Yes", is there one one for Auto Rename?
Or a code that renames it without going through cmd questionnaires?
Or perhaps even a command that extracts it in its own hierarchy if you know what I mean? That is it the top file extracts and then its sub zip folders extract into it etc.

Anything to help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Open the `7-zip` help and read the `-ao (Overwrite mode) switch` section.

Comment: your `Path` is clearly wrong, also superfluous.

Comment: Thank you foxidrive the switch -aou was perfect. speising, do I not need to put the PATH?

Comment: I think the point @foxidrive was making was that because you are already supplying the full path to 7z.exe in each line, you don't need to (also) add it to your PATH variable.